# How to write SOAP clients in PHP?

Tags: php, soap

Need simple code/ suggestion for SOAP client in php

**Sample Request**

```
<soapenv:Envelope
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:sch="http://somewebsite.com/Publisher/schemas">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sch:GetCampaignsRequest>
         <sch:username>myusername</sch:username>
         <sch:password>mypassword</sch:password>
         <sch:approvaltype>approved</sch:approvaltype>
      </sch:GetCampaignsRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have try with below php code but I am getting error

**Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in E:\xampp\htdocs\soap\test.php on line 0**

```
$params = array('username' => 'username','password' => 'password','approvaltype'=>'approved');

$client=new SoapClient('http://somewebsite.com/Publisher.v1.1/publisher.wsdl', array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));

$result = $client->GetCampaignsRequest($params);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a higher execution timeout (or none).

```
<?php
set_time_limit( 0);
int_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Comment: It won't work if your hosting provider doesn't let you modify this setting (very likely). Start up your own local web server using XAMP / WAMP and see if the timeout is the problem.